# How to Delete State Machine Executions?

Tags: aws-step-functions

Say I want to keep a `StateMachine`, but have old `Executions` which have finished that I don't want to keep around anymore, is there any way to delete those or do they have a TTL? We plan to run quite a few `StepFunctions` each day, and I was hoping there is a TTL on how long `Executions` live for once they are finished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After running many many Step Functions, I can see that AWS keeps 1,000 executions in the console. As far as I can see from the docs & the API, there is no way to delete executions. If you delete your `StateMachine`, that would also delete the associated executions, but otherwise you would need to wait till you have run 1k more till your `StateMachine` execution died.

For this reason I would also recommend not using the ability to query executions for monitoring purposes.

Comment: what should be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

AWS keeps at least 2k executions for us. I can not find a documented limit.